# Matrix of orthogonal rows

Tags: linear-algebra

There are general properties for a matrix $A$ to find out is it orthogonally diagonalizable or not?

I want to find out a given arbitrary matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable or not. For example I know the symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case) states that a matrix $A$ with real entries will be orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if it is symmetric.